# Correct way of computing a covariance matrix of two matrices with different number of features and same number of observations

Tags: python, numpy

What is the proper way of computing the covariance matrix of two matices, X of shape `(n x p)` and Y of shape `(n x q)`

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([np.random.normal(size=10),
         np.random.normal(size=10),
         np.random.normal(size=10)]).T

Y = np.array([np.random.normal(size=10),
         np.random.normal(size=10),
         np.random.normal(size=10),
         np.random.normal(size=10)]).T
```

Doing `np.cov(X,Y)` returns an error.

But `np.cov(X.T, Y.T)` does not

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

```
y : array_like, optional

    An additional set of variables and observations.
    y has the same form as that of m.
```

The shape of the matrices is not equal. I suppose the numpy authors forgot to check the dimensions in the first case. I have no other explanation for that. Possibly the computations are run on a subarray of Y in the first case. Possibly this is already fixed in newer version of numpy or you can consider to send a bug report.